# Schedule / trigger action realtime and absolute in rails when a certain condition is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, resque

Im looking for a way to trigger a certain action absolute and in realtime without delay in ruby on rails when a certain condition is TRUE.

A simplified example to illustrate this:

```
**table times**
id  | time    
1     12:00
2     12.05
3     13:00
```

- Checking every second, to see if the current_time == times in db table
- If TRUE then it should execute a piece of code ( function ) directly with no delays

I have looked into resque and delayed_jobs but the problem is those do not support a absolute realtime execution they just add to a queue which could cause delays in the execution, it can be a second of max

Anyone has experience with above case and could point me to the best practice on how to implement above in Ruby on rails?

Comment: I end up writing a custom rake task, wich is called with delayed gem every few seconds

Answer (score 0):

I end up writing a custom rake task, wich is called with delayed gem every few seconds